# BackgroundWorker multiple results

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I'm new to C#/.NET programming and I have a question.

I use `BackgroundWorker` to fetch XML data from server.

The problem is that data is paginated. After I get a page I should check if there are another page available and fetch it next.

But I don't want to make the user wait till (dozen or more) pages will be loaded. And I can't make parallel requests to server due API ToS (and I don't know how many pages are there).

What I want is to display (via DataGridView) each page of data as soon as possible. Some kind of pseudo-`yield`.

Is it possible with `BackgroundWorker` or I have to use something else (I use .NET 4, VS2012)

Comment: In the reportprogress you can handle all changes on the main GUI. This is to keep the software responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the `public void ReportProgress(int percentProgress,Object userState)` method with the `XmlNode` segment as your state object each time your background worker retrieves a page. This will trigger the `ProgressChanged` event.

Keep the worker running until you run out of pages. Here's an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ywkkz4s1.aspx